# Como fazer para meu Salvar, Alterar o os dados do meu banco

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

Galera, estou tentando fazer um `Button` que normalmente Salva, virar também um `Button` que salva as alterações feitas... É tudo na mesma `form` e o mesmo `Button`, por exemplo quando dou dois Click Na Célula do `DataGrid` ele traz pra mim nos `TextBox` as informações, porém se eu editá-las ele cadastra como um novo registro, e eu queria salvar as alterações feitas do registro selecionado, se alguém puder dar uma luz, agradeço

Código que estou usando abaixo

```
 //criando a bool
        bool informacoesSalvas = false;

        private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNome.Text))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("O nome do produto está vazio, por favor digite algo");
            return; // sai do método
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPreco.Text))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("O Preço do produto está vazio, por favor digite algo");
            return;
        }

        else if (informacoesSalvas)
        {

            // Abre a conexão
            conectar.Open();

            //Query SQL
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Produto (Nome,Descricao,Preco,status)" +
            "VALUES('" + txtNome + "','" + txtDescricao.Text + "','" + txtPreco.Text + "'," + ckbAtiv.Checked + " )", conectar);

            //Executa a Query SQL
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Fecha a conexão
            conectar.Close();

            //Mensagem de Sucesso
            MessageBox.Show("Alterado com Sucesso!", "Informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            informacoesSalvas = true;
        }
        else
        {

            conectar.Open();
            //Convertendo

            Converter = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPreco.Text);

            //MessageBox.Show("Conectado");

            MySqlCommand Inserir = new MySqlCommand();
            Inserir.Connection = conectar;
            Inserir.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Produto (Nome, Descricao, Preco, `status`) VALUES (@peca, @nome, @quantidade, @dataentrada)";

            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peca", txtNome.Text);
            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtDescricao.Text);
            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", txtPreco.Text);
            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataentrada", ckbAtiv.Checked);

            Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conectar.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Produto Cadastrado", "Concluido",
              MessageBoxButtons.OK,
              MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            selecionarCategoria();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note que na sua query SQL ambas as partes do if fazem a operação de insert, que no seu caso seria uma update e uma insert.

```
UPDATE Produto SET Nome = @NOME, Descricao = @DESCRICAO, PRECO = @PRECO, STATUS = @STATUS WHERE ID = @ID
```

Note que ao fazer o `UPDATE` eu passo um ID como condição no WHERE, isso para que apenas o registro desejado seja alterado. Dica: nunca esqueça do `WHERE`

Comment: isso eu teria que fazer no banco ou no proprio C# mesmo ?

Comment: fiz ele em um outro `Button` pra ver se ficava melhor mas aparentemente está dando um outro erro, se puder dar uma olhada la [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371435/como-alterar-um-dado-no-bd)